# How to use filter tags in tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm using tensorboard ver:1.10.0 scalars to visualize the loss. How to use these filter tags field? Can I use regular expression to filter my x and y axis, eg: y>100? Or do I need to add tags in `writer.add_summary`? Your help is much appreciated.

Please find the screenshot below:

[image: Tensorboard scalar]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tag is specified by the names you give, when calling `tf.summary.scalar("loss", tensor)`. For this example and yours, too, "loss" is the tag. It makes sense, when you have multiple summaries of several different runs in your tfboard.